# UINavigation setViewControllers: memory allocation

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, memory-management

I am using setViewControllers on navigationcontroller like :

```
XYZController *xyz = [XYZController alloc] initWithXibName:@"XYZController"];
[myNavController setViewControllers:xyz];
[xyz release];
```

I am checking the allocations in instruments, however i found that as many time this  function call live object in instruments increase, if this function being called 5 time instrument shows in #live for 5 times.

That means it is allocating the memory, how do i handle memory allocation on this.

---

**EDIT** :

```
RootViewController *rootController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootController];
[rootController.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
[self.myNavController setViewControllers:nil];
[self.myNavController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController,nil]];
[rootController release];
[navController release];
```

This is the actual code I am using in my application. The issue here is rootController living objects count in instruments always increases whenever there is a call to this piece of code. Not only rootController count increases but also the class variables are also not released hence, the memory piles up. The result being the performance of my application degrades to a large extent.

Please advise on this.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, instruments can often provide false positives when viewing memory allocations so I would take these warnings with a pinch of salt. It shouldn't be mounting up as (aside from the errors with your code) it looks fairly valid to me.

Secondly, your code is incorrect as `myNavController` (which I assume is a `UINavigationController`) would crash when calling `setViewControllers` as it expects an array of `UIViewController`'s, not a single view controller as you have above. This would most likely crash, or not even compile.

Check your code is valid and run instruments again. If you still have the same issue, it's probably just a false positive and should be ignored.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. `myNavController` is a `UINavigationController` and `setViewControllers` contains only single view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't test for memory usage with zombies on (NSZombiesEnabled argument, or in Scheme Diagnostics). Zombies by default are never deleted.